# Does omniauth-saml support only SHA1?

Tags: ruby, omniauth, saml

We would like to update the certificate that we use with our SAML integrations to SHA256.  We're using the omniauth-saml and ruby-saml gems to implement SSO.

Based on this code, it looks like omniauth-saml assumes that the IdP's certificate uses SHA1.
https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/saml.rb#L96

So, two questions:
1) Is there any way to allow the IdP to use a different hashing algorithm with omniauth-saml?
2) Would it work for us to upgrade our cert to SHA256, while still leaving the IdP's cert on SHA1?

Comment: That's just producing a fingerprint. Given that SHA1 is toast it's probably a good idea to patch that, however I'm not sure that presumes anything about the certificte's hash.

Answer (score 0):

Looks tadman is right, and the answer to my question is that code does not mean that omniauth-saml does not support other hashing algorithms.

What that code says is: use the SHA1 algorithm to generate a *fingerprint*.  It does not care what algorithm was used to generate the original certificate.

Comment: so omniauth-saml supports SHA256 certificates as idp_cert ?

Comment: Yep.  Most of the IdP certificates that our customers use are signed with SHA256.